# Rails gem dependency when trying to install reac-on-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, react-on-rails

Hi I am trying to install react_on_rails in an existing project. I add

```
gem 'react_on_rails'
```

to my gem file and run bundle install. I get this error message:
[image]

So I run bundle update and get this: 
[image]

Updating ruby is a last resort at this point, is there any other way I can make the gems work together? I installed react-on-rails in a blank rails project using the same version of ruby I am using now (2.1.6) and it worked fin. Here is my Gemfile.lock

```
  GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
  CFPropertyList (2.3.2)
  aasm (3.2.0)
actionmailer (4.1.9)
  actionpack (= 4.1.9)
  actionview (= 4.1.9)
  mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
  actionpack (4.1.9)
  actionview (= 4.1.9)
  activesupport (= 4.1.9)
  rack (~> 1.5.2)
  rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
actionview (4.1.9)
  activesupport (= 4.1.9)
  builder (~> 3.1)
  erubis (~> 2.7.0)
active_model_serializers (0.8.1)
  activemodel (>= 3.0)
activemodel (4.1.9)
  activesupport (= 4.1.9)
  builder (~> 3.1)
activerecord (4.1.9)
  activemodel (= 4.1.9)
  activesupport (= 4.1.9)
  arel (~> 5.0.0)
activesupport (4.1.9)
  i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.9)
  json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
  minitest (~> 5.1)
  thread_safe (~> 0.1)
  tzinfo (~> 1.1)
addressable (2.3.6)
annotate (2.6.3)
  activerecord (>= 2.3.0)
  rake (>= 0.8.7)
arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
aws-sdk (2.6.5)
  aws-sdk-resources (= 2.6.5)
aws-sdk-core (2.6.5)
  jmespath (~> 1.0)
aws-sdk-rails (1.0.1)
  aws-sdk-resources (~> 2)
  railties (>= 3)
aws-sdk-resources (2.6.5)
  aws-sdk-core (= 2.6.5)
bcrypt (3.1.7)
better_errors (1.1.0)
  coderay (>= 1.0.0)
  erubis (>= 2.6.6)
binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
  debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
bourbon (3.2.3)
  sass (~> 3.2)
  thor
builder (3.2.2)
byebug (4.0.5)
  columnize (= 0.9.0)
capistrano (3.0.1)
  i18n
  rake (>= 10.0.0)
  sshkit (>= 0.0.23)
capistrano-bundler (1.0.0)
  capistrano (>= 3.0.0.pre)
capistrano-rails (1.1.0)
  capistrano (>= 3.0.0)
  capistrano-bundler (>= 1.0.0)
carrierwave (0.10.0)
  activemodel (>= 3.2.0)
  activesupport (>= 3.2.0)
  json (>= 1.7)
  mime-types (>= 1.16)
celluloid (0.15.2)
  timers (~> 1.1.0)
chartkick (1.5.2)
choice (0.1.6)
chronic (0.10.2)
coderay (1.1.0)
coffee-rails (4.0.1)
  coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
  railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
  coffee-script-source
  execjs
coffee-script-source (1.7.0)
cohort_me (0.0.3)
columnize (0.9.0)
crack (0.4.2)
  safe_yaml (~> 1.0.0)
daemons (1.1.9)
database_cleaner (1.3.0)
debug_inspector (0.0.2)
deep_cloneable (2.2.2)
  activerecord (>= 3.1.0, < 5.2.0)
devise (3.2.4)
  bcrypt (~> 3.0)
  orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
  railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
  thread_safe (~> 0.1)
  warden (~> 1.2.3)
diff-lcs (1.3)
docile (1.1.3)
dotenv (0.7.0)
em-websocket (0.5.1)
  eventmachine (>= 0.12.9)
  http_parser.rb (~> 0.6.0)
email_validator (1.4.0)
  activemodel
erubis (2.7.0)
eventmachine (1.0.3)
excon (0.45.4)
execjs (2.1.0)
factory_girl (4.4.0)
  activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
factory_girl_rails (4.4.1)
  factory_girl (~> 4.4.0)
  railties (>= 3.0.0)
faker (1.2.0)
  i18n (~> 0.5)
faraday (0.9.0)
  multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)
fast_stack (0.1.0)
  rake
  rake-compiler
ffi (1.9.3)
fission (0.5.0)
  CFPropertyList (~> 2.2)
flamegraph (0.1.0)
  fast_stack
flutie (2.0.0)
fog (1.37.0)
  fog-aliyun (>= 0.1.0)
  fog-atmos
  fog-aws (>= 0.6.0)
  fog-brightbox (~> 0.4)
  fog-core (~> 1.32)
  fog-dynect (~> 0.0.2)
  fog-ecloud (~> 0.1)
  fog-google (<= 0.1.0)
  fog-json
  fog-local
  fog-powerdns (>= 0.1.1)
  fog-profitbricks
  fog-radosgw (>= 0.0.2)
  fog-riakcs
  fog-sakuracloud (>= 0.0.4)
  fog-serverlove
  fog-softlayer
  fog-storm_on_demand
  fog-terremark
  fog-vmfusion
  fog-voxel
  fog-vsphere (>= 0.4.0)
  fog-xenserver
  fog-xml (~> 0.1.1)
  ipaddress (~> 0.5)
fog-aliyun (0.1.0)
  fog-core (~> 1.27)
  fog-json (~> 1.0)
  ipaddress (~> 0.8)
  xml-simple (~> 1.1)
fog-atmos (0.1.0)
  fog-core
  fog-xml
fog-aws (0.7.6)
  fog-core (~> 1.27)
  fog-json (~> 1.0)
  fog-xml (~> 0.1)
  ipaddress (~> 0.8)
fog-brightbox (0.10.1)
  fog-core (~> 1.22)
  fog-json
  inflecto (~> 0.0.2)
fog-core (1.35.0)
  builder
  excon (~> 0.45)
  formatador (~> 0.2)
fog-dynect (0.0.2)
  fog-core
  fog-json
  fog-xml
fog-ecloud (0.3.0)
  fog-core
  fog-xml
fog-google (0.1.0)
  fog-core
  fog-json
  fog-xml
fog-json (1.0.2)
  fog-core (~> 1.0)
  multi_json (~> 1.10)
fog-local (0.2.1)
  fog-core (~> 1.27)
fog-powerdns (0.1.1)
  fog-core (~> 1.27)
  fog-json (~> 1.0)
  fog-xml (~> 0.1)
fog-profitbricks (0.0.5)
  fog-core
  fog-xml
  nokogiri
fog-radosgw (0.0.4)
  fog-core (>= 1.21.0)
  fog-json
  fog-xml (>= 0.0.1)
fog-riakcs (0.1.0)
  fog-core
  fog-json
  fog-xml
fog-sakuracloud (1.7.3)
  fog-core
  fog-json
fog-serverlove (0.1.2)
  fog-core
  fog-json
fog-softlayer (1.0.2)
  fog-core
  fog-json
fog-storm_on_demand (0.1.1)
  fog-core
  fog-json
fog-terremark (0.1.0)
  fog-core
  fog-xml
fog-vmfusion (0.1.0)
  fission
  fog-core
fog-voxel (0.1.0)
  fog-core
  fog-xml
fog-vsphere (0.4.0)
  fog-core
  rbvmomi (~> 1.8)
fog-xenserver (0.2.2)
  fog-core
  fog-xml
fog-xml (0.1.2)
  fog-core
  nokogiri (~> 1.5, >= 1.5.11)
font-awesome-rails (4.6.1.0)
  railties (>= 3.2, < 5.1)
foreman (0.66.0)
  dotenv (~> 0.7.0)
  thor (~> 0.19.1)
formatador (0.2.5)
foundation-rails (5.4.5.0)
  railties (>= 3.1.0)
  sass (>= 3.2.0)
foundation-wysihtml5-rails (1.0.0)
  railties (>= 3.0)
fullcalendar-rails (2.0.2.0)
geokit (1.10.0)
geokit-rails (2.2.0)
  geokit (~> 1.5)
  rails (>= 3.0)
gmaps4rails (2.1.2)
groupdate (2.5.3)
  activesupport (>= 3)
guard (2.6.1)
  formatador (>= 0.2.4)
  listen (~> 2.7)
  lumberjack (~> 1.0)
  pry (>= 0.9.12)
  thor (>= 0.18.1)
guard-livereload (2.2.0)
  em-websocket (~> 0.5)
  guard (~> 2.0)
  multi_json (~> 1.8)
haml (4.0.5)
  tilt
haml-rails (0.5.3)
  actionpack (>= 4.0.1)
  activesupport (>= 4.0.1)
  haml (>= 3.1, < 5.0)
  railties (>= 4.0.1)
hashie (3.2.0)
hike (1.2.3)
http_parser.rb (0.6.0)
httparty (0.13.1)
  json (~> 1.8)
  multi_xml (>= 0.5.2)
hubspot-ruby (0.2.1)
  activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
  httparty (>= 0.10.0)
i18n (0.7.0)
icalendar (2.2.0)
inflecto (0.0.2)
infusionsoft (1.1.8)
ipaddress (0.8.0)
jbuilder (2.2.6)
  activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5)
  multi_json (~> 1.2)
jmespath (1.3.1)
jquery-cookie-rails (1.3.1.1)
  railties (>= 3.2.0, < 5.0)
jquery-rails (3.1.0)
  railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
  thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
json (1.8.2)
jwt (1.0.0)
kaminari (0.15.1)
  actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
  activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
kgio (2.9.2)
launchy (2.4.2)
  addressable (~> 2.3)
listen (2.7.5)
  celluloid (>= 0.15.2)
  rb-fsevent (>= 0.9.3)
  rb-inotify (>= 0.9)
lumberjack (1.0.6)
mail (2.6.3)
  mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3)
mandrill-api (1.0.53)
  excon (>= 0.16.0, < 1.0)
  json (>= 1.7.7, < 2.0)
method_source (0.8.2)
mime-types (1.25.1)
mini_portile2 (2.0.0)
minitest (5.5.1)
momentjs-rails (2.8.3)
  railties (>= 3.1)
multi_json (1.11.2)
multi_xml (0.5.5)
multipart-post (2.0.0)
net-scp (1.2.1)
  net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
net-ssh (3.0.1)
newrelic_rpm (3.14.2.312)
nokogiri (1.6.7.1)
  mini_portile2 (~> 2.0.0.rc2)
oauth2 (1.0.0)
  faraday (>= 0.8, < 0.10)
  jwt (~> 1.0)
  multi_json (~> 1.3)
  multi_xml (~> 0.5)
  rack (~> 1.2)
omniauth (1.2.2)
  hashie (>= 1.2, < 4)
  rack (~> 1.0)
omniauth-facebook (2.0.0)
  omniauth-oauth2 (~> 1.2)
omniauth-oauth2 (1.2.0)
  faraday (>= 0.8, < 0.10)
  multi_json (~> 1.3)
  oauth2 (~> 1.0)
  omniauth (~> 1.2)
orm_adapter (0.5.0)
paper_trail (4.0.0.beta2)
  activerecord (>= 3.0, < 6.0)
  activesupport (>= 3.0, < 6.0)
pdf-core (0.7.0)
pg (0.17.1)
prawn (2.2.2)
  pdf-core (~> 0.7.0)
  ttfunk (~> 1.5)
prawn-table (0.2.2)
  prawn (>= 1.3.0, < 3.0.0)
pry (0.9.12.6)
  coderay (~> 1.0)
  method_source (~> 0.8)
  slop (~> 3.4)
pry-remote (0.1.8)
  pry (~> 0.9)
  slop (~> 3.0)
quiet_assets (1.0.2)
  railties (>= 3.1, < 5.0)
rack (1.5.2)
rack-attack (5.0.1)
  rack
rack-cors (0.4.1)
rack-test (0.6.3)
  rack (>= 1.0)
rack-timeout (0.0.4)
rails (4.1.9)
  actionmailer (= 4.1.9)
  actionpack (= 4.1.9)
  actionview (= 4.1.9)
  activemodel (= 4.1.9)
  activerecord (= 4.1.9)
  activesupport (= 4.1.9)
  bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
  railties (= 4.1.9)
  sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
rails-erd (1.1.0)
  activerecord (>= 3.0)
  activesupport (>= 3.0)
  choice (~> 0.1.6)
  ruby-graphviz (~> 1.0.4)
railties (4.1.9)
  actionpack (= 4.1.9)
  activesupport (= 4.1.9)
  rake (>= 0.8.7)
  thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
raindrops (0.13.0)
rake (10.4.2)
rake-compiler (0.9.5)
  rake
rb-fsevent (0.9.4)
rb-inotify (0.9.4)
  ffi (>= 0.5.0)
rbvmomi (1.8.2)
  builder
  nokogiri (>= 1.4.1)
  trollop
recipient_interceptor (0.1.2)
  mail
redcarpet (3.1.2)
render_csv (2.0.0)
  rails (>= 3.0)
rest-client (1.6.7)
  mime-types (>= 1.16)
ri_cal (0.8.8)
rmagick (2.13.4)
rspec-core (3.5.4)
  rspec-support (~> 3.5.0)
rspec-expectations (3.5.0)
  diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
  rspec-support (~> 3.5.0)
rspec-mocks (3.5.0)
  diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
  rspec-support (~> 3.5.0)
rspec-rails (3.5.2)
  actionpack (>= 3.0)
  activesupport (>= 3.0)
  railties (>= 3.0)
  rspec-core (~> 3.5.0)
  rspec-expectations (~> 3.5.0)
  rspec-mocks (~> 3.5.0)
  rspec-support (~> 3.5.0)
rspec-support (3.5.0)
ruby-graphviz (1.0.9)
safe_yaml (1.0.3)
sass (3.4.12)
sass-rails (5.0.1)
  railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
  sass (~> 3.1)
  sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
  sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
  tilt (~> 1.1)
seed_dump (3.2.1)
  activerecord (~> 4)
  activesupport (~> 4)
shoulda-matchers (2.6.1)
  activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
simplecov (0.8.2)
  docile (~> 1.1.0)
  multi_json
  simplecov-html (~> 0.8.0)
simplecov-html (0.8.0)
slack-notifier (2.1.0)
slop (3.5.0)
smarty_streets (0.0.6)
  httparty (~> 0.11)
sprockets (2.12.3)
  hike (~> 1.2)
  multi_json (~> 1.0)
  rack (~> 1.0)
  tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
sprockets-rails (2.2.4)
  actionpack (>= 3.0)
  activesupport (>= 3.0)
  sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
sshkit (1.1.0)
  net-scp
  net-ssh
  term-ansicolor
stripe (1.9.9)
  mime-types (~> 1.25)
  multi_json (>= 1.0.4, < 2)
  rest-client (~> 1.4)
term-ansicolor (1.3.0)
  tins (~> 1.0)
thin (1.6.2)
  daemons (>= 1.0.9)
  eventmachine (>= 1.0.0)
  rack (>= 1.0.0)
thor (0.19.1)
thread_safe (0.3.4)
tilt (1.4.1)
timecop (0.7.1)
timers (1.1.0)
tins (1.5.1)
trollop (2.1.2)
ttfunk (1.5.0)
twilio-ruby (3.11.5)
  builder (>= 2.1.2)
  jwt (>= 0.1.2)
  multi_json (>= 1.3.0)
tzinfo (1.2.2)
  thread_safe (~> 0.1)
uglifier (2.5.0)
  execjs (>= 0.3.0)
  json (>= 1.8.0)
underscore-rails (1.8.3)
unicorn (4.8.3)
  kgio (~> 2.6)
  rack
  raindrops (~> 0.7)
unicorn-rails (2.1.1)
  rack
  unicorn
warden (1.2.3)
  rack (>= 1.0)
web-console (2.2.1)
  activemodel (>= 4.0)
  binding_of_caller (>= 0.7.2)
  railties (>= 4.0)
  sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
webmock (1.18.0)
  addressable (>= 2.3.6)
  crack (>= 0.3.2)
whenever (0.9.4)
  chronic (>= 0.6.3)
xml-simple (1.1.5)

PLATFORMS
ruby

DEPENDENCIES
aasm (~> 3.2.0)
active_model_serializers (~> 0.8.1)
annotate
aws-sdk
aws-sdk-rails
better_errors
binding_of_caller
bourbon
byebug
capistrano
capistrano-rails
carrierwave
chartkick
chronic
coffee-rails
cohort_me
database_cleaner
deep_cloneable (~> 2.2.2)
devise
email_validator
factory_girl_rails
faker
flamegraph
flutie
fog
font-awesome-rails
foreman
foundation-rails (= 5.4.5.0)
foundation-wysihtml5-rails
fullcalendar-rails
geokit
geokit-rails
gmaps4rails
groupdate
guard-livereload
haml-rails
httparty (~> 0.13.1)
hubspot-ruby
icalendar
infusionsoft
jbuilder
jquery-cookie-rails
jquery-rails
kaminari (~> 0.15.1)
launchy
mandrill-api
momentjs-rails
newrelic_rpm
omniauth-facebook
paper_trail (~> 4.0.0.beta)
pg
prawn
prawn-table
pry
pry-remote
quiet_assets
rack-attack
rack-cors
rack-timeout
rails (>= 4.0.0)
rails-erd
recipient_interceptor
redcarpet
render_csv
rest-client
ri_cal
rmagick
rspec-rails (~> 3.5)
sass-rails
seed_dump
shoulda-matchers
simplecov
slack-notifier
smarty_streets
stripe
thin
timecop
twilio-ruby (~> 3.11.5)
uglifier
underscore-rails
unicorn-rails
web-console (~> 2.0)
webmock
whenever

BUNDLED WITH
 1.14.6
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the gems get downloaded to the wrong path.

Add this path, so rbenv loads before the system ruby

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
```